# Flowplayer 5.0 with playlist - CSS issues

Tags: css, flowplayer

I am using the latest Flowplayer (5.0, which is HTML5 first and foremost... yay!) to play tutorial videos on a private site (so I cannot provide a living sample). I am trying to use the built-in playlist functionality. The formatting is all wonky.

Here is a screen capture of the problem. Note that the red outline is the "flowplayer" area as calculated by the tool. The Windows taskbar and Firefox browser are the video capture itself. The Flowplayer controls are that wee little timeline strip a bit below the video (near the bottom of the "flowplayer" area).

[image: flowplayer bad css]

The suggested code from the Flowplayer site is as follows:

```
<div class="flowplayer">

   <!-- initial clip -->
   <video>
      <source type="video/webm" src="night1/640x360.webm"/>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="night1/640x360.mp4"/>
      <source type="video/ogg" src="night1/640x360.ogv"/>
   </video>

   <!-- playlist root -->
   <div class="fp-playlist">

      <!-- playlist entries so. "trigger" elements -->
      <a href="night1.mp4"></a>
      <a href="night2.mp4"></a>
      <a href="night3.mp4"></a>
      <a href="night4.mp4"></a>
   </div>

</div>
```

I am using the included skins... none of them work, but let's say for the sake of argument I am using "functional.css".

The problems:

1. The control elements are escaping the "video player" zone by a large margin. In other words, that "timeline bar" you can see at the bottom of the area is actually MEANT to be snugged up against the video area.

I finally identified the problem: height of the video area is being set to "100%"; however, this is based on the entire `.flowplayer` area. Since this area includes the playlist, "100%" is larger than the video itself.

2. Related, the playlist is above the video instead of below it. This certainly has to do with the absolute positioning used within the `.flowplayer` area to position controls.
3. As per point #2, even if the video area is resized, the playlist is positioned such that it gets obscured by the video area.

Here's what I've tried:

- If I calculate the desired height and explicitly set it to, for example, 400px instead of 100%, the controls line up properly. This is proof of concept, though, since it's suboptimal. I want to use ratio of some sort (like 100%!) so that it can render in a responsive layout.
- As soon as I float elements or otherwise change the approach to layout, I have to update absolutely everything. I can do this, but it's surprising to me that the provided CSS and the provided sample code will not render.
- I have looked for conflicts with site CSS; there are none that I can see. This layout seems to be strictly caused by the way the flowplayer elements are nested.
- I have moved the playlist outside of `.flowplayer`; however, it must use that container in the script (and why wouldn't it? It makes perfect sense to do that!) in order to identify and attach events to the playlist.

---

Anybody every come across this or have any ideas? The end result should be a dynamically-reisizable flowplayer area, with a playlist below it.

Thanks for any insight you might have, or 3rd party skins that might solve the problem. ;-)